# Family of finite groups "universal with respect to epimorphisms"

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

The Cayley theorem states that every group is isomorphic to a permutation group. This can be rephrased as follows: for each finite group $G$ there is a positive integer $n$ and a monomorphism from $G$ to $S_n$. Therefore the family $(S_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is universal in the sense that any group is isomorphic to a subgroup of some family member.

Can we find a family with similar property, but with "epi" instead of "mono"? Ie., is there a reasonable family of finite groups, such that every finite group is a quotient group of some family member?

(By "reasonable" I mean something "smaller" than the family of all finite groups and not constructed specifically for our purpose.)

Comment: Your rephrasing is true only for finite groups.

Comment: True, I've made an edit.

Comment: Use "surjection" rather than "epimorphism". Epimorphism means "cancellable on the right", and while in many classes of groups it is they are equivalent, in some natural classes not every epimorphism is surjective.

Comment: By construction, the free groups are a canonical family satisfying this property. But a nontrivial free group is never finite, so it wouldn’t quite work.

Comment: Leaving a "bad" family here in case someone can make something useful of it: For each $n$, there are only finitely many groups of order $n$ (up to isomorphism). Define $G_n$ to be the direct product of these groups. Then, $(G_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has the desired property.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've seen a definition "group epimorphism = surjective group homomorphism", although it might be a thing just for my country. The "appropriate", categorical definition is, I believe, equivalent for all groups and for finite groups, so I'll stay with my current phrasing. But thanks for making me aware of this issue.

Comment: It's not country-related. A lot of people "define" epimorphism to mean surjective. But it causes needless problems and potential confusions as there are many contexts in which the two notions do not agree. In fact, they fail to agree much more often than they agree.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking every group in the family was supposed to be a quotient of the finite group, not the reverse for some reason.